# Can I use PowerShell instead of AppCmd.exe to monitor IIS state?

Tags: iis, powershell, appcmd

I want to write a script that uses appcmd.exe to monitor IIS state - 
restart a site if it's down and/or restart IIS if it's down.

Can this be done with powershell? is there a more natural/easier method of doing this?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Windows PowerShell is always the Answer!  This should do it for your particular question:

```
# Cycle IIS if it's not running    
Get-Service W3SVC  |
    Where-Object {$_.Status -ne 'Running' }  | 
    Start-Service

Import-Module WebAdministration

# Cycle websites that are not started
Get-Website | 
    Where-Object { $_.State -ne 'Started' }  | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.Start() }
```

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WebAdministration` module to do it in a more elegant way than using appcmd.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx